# ¿Como puedo hacer un método para cambiar los caracteres de un string al caracter siguiente de el abecedario en Java?

Tags: java, string, print, replace, char

Como puedo hacer un método para cambiar los caracteres de un string al caracter siguiente de el abecedario, dado un número de desplazamiento.

● Por ejemplo, con desplazo de 1:

“hola que tal” -> “ipmbarvfaubm”

h -> i
o -> p

con desplazo de 2

“hola que tal” -> “jqncbswgbvcn”

h -> j
o -> q

Comment: Hola  gfc225, bienvenido, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String saludo = "hola que tal";
int desplazamiento = 1;
char saludoCharArray[] = saludo.toCharArray();
for( int i = 0; i < saludoCharArray.length; i ++ ) {
   saludoCharArray[ i ] += desplazamiento;
}
String salida = new String( saludoCharArray );
System.out.println( salida );
```

desplazamiento = 1 -> ipmb!rvf!ubm
desplazamiento = 2 -> jqnc"swg"vcn

Creamos un `array` de `char`, al que instanciamos con el método **`toCharArray`**, que recibe una cadena y devuelve un `array` de `char's`.
Dado que el `char` no almacena un caracter, sino su representación numérica, podemos tratarlo como a cualquier número (bueno, no tanto).
Con el `for`, modificamos el valor de cada `char` individual.
Por último creamos un objeto `String`, pasandole como parámetro el `array` de `char's`.

Comment: Ayúdanos a mantener la calidad de la información en el sitio respondiendo preguntas basadas en [ask],. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede usar la tabla ASCII para obtener el siguiente carácter al actual, e ir concatenando todos como lo hace el siguiente método:

```
public static String getShiftedWord(String word, Integer shift){
    String wordCpy = word.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    String shiftedWord = "";
    for (int i=0; i < wordCpy.length() ; i ++){
        int shiftedAscii = (int) wordCpy.charAt(i) + shift;
        shiftedWord += (char) shiftedAscii;
    };
    return shiftedWord;
};

System.out.println(Main.getShiftedWord("hola como estas",1)); // ipmbdpnpftubt
```

Comment: Ayúdanos a mantener la calidad de la información en el sitio respondiendo preguntas basadas en [ask],. Saludos.